# Uploading data from LocalStorage to a Web Application

Tags: google-chrome-extension, upload, cors, local-storage

I have a web application that requires an offline option.

I have built an offline form in an HTML page that lives on local machines and writes to localStorage.

The offline app uses an eventListener to determine when there is an internet connection and then sends the data in localStorage to the web application over JSON (xmlHttpRequest).

The problem is that the request is cross-domain (from the personal computer's drive to the web application), so it returns "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

I've investigated using CORS and it seems like it would work for this as long as I set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin parameter to "*".

Are there any other options for uploading localStorage data to a web server from a personal computer?

Looking forward to hearing suggestions. Please don't hesitate to request further details if necessary.

Thanks, Noah

Comment: If you open that local page via file:// URL, I think I've seen a discussion on https://crbug.com that the observed behavior is intended in Chrome for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, I believe that cross-domain requests are seen as a security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding the following header to the page in my web application that is responsible for processing the JSON data.

```
Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"
```

I recognize that this opens up the application to all origins and that this can pose a security risk, but I have implemented a token to ensure that data only comes from the offline version of the app. Also, there was no alternative because all the requests will come from file://, not other domains that could be cataloged.

Hope this helps someone! Cheers, N

Comment: Does anyone know if the header can be configured to only allow access from file:// ?